# java.io.InvalidClassException: local class incompatible - Apache Spark Submit issue for more than one worker

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-submit

We have been trying to run a java application in Apache Spark using master-worker architecture. Below is the pom.xml for java application:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Final</groupId>
    <artifactId>DLSH</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Below is the spark configuration for the java application:

```
            SparkSession spark = SparkSession
                  .builder()
                  .appName("JavaBucketedRandomProjectionLSHExample")
                  .master(args[0])
                  .getOrCreate();
```

**Java Version Used-11**

- This works fine when I try running using spark-submit by setting the master-URL with one worker node.

**Actual Issue:**

- When I try to run the program in two worker nodes(two different machines using same network) using spark-submit, then I faced the *local class incompatible issue.*

**Below is the command I used to run with two worker nodes using spark-submit:**

- *./spark-master.sh*- To start the master
- *./spark-slave.sh "Master-URL"* - To start the workers

Below is the spark WEB UI for the above config:

```
3.1.0-SNAPSHOT Spark Master at spark://mushfiq:7077

    URL: spark://mushfiq:7077
    Alive Workers: 2
    Cores in use: 16 Total, 0 Used
    Memory in use: 29.2 GiB Total, 0.0 B Used
    Resources in use:
    Applications: 0 Running, 34 Completed
    Drivers: 0 Running, 0 Completed
    Status: ALIVE

Workers (2)
Worker Id                                         Address            State    Cores     Memory  
worker-20200617123647-128.123.63.43-45983   128.123.63.43:45983     ALIVE   8 (0 Used)  14.6 GiB (0.0 B Used)   
worker-20200617124042-128.123.63.78-34355   128.123.63.78:34355     ALIVE   8 (0 Used)  14.6 GiB (0.0 B Used)
```

Below is the spark-submit command used to execute the java application jar using the above two worker nodes:

```
./spark-submit --class DistributedLSH.Application /home/mushfiq/Desktop/Eclipse/DLSHlatest.jar spark://mushfiq:7077 /home/mushfiq/Desktop/LSH/Datasets/Color/Color.ds /home/mushfiq/Desktop/LSH/Datasets/Color/randomdata.ds
```

**Explanation of the above command:**

```
./spark-submit --class <ClassName> 
<Path to Jar File("/home.../DSHlatest.jar")>
<args[0]-Master URL(spark://mushfiq:7077)>
<args[1](/home/..../Color.ds)>
<args[2](/home/.....randomdata.ds)>
```

**Apache spark version for spark-submit**- We used the following GitHub version for spark-submit - [Apache Spark version](https://github.com/apache/spark)

**Question**

- So, when we run the above command, we get the following exception:

```
Lost task 1.3 in stage 2.0 (TID 9, 128.123.63.78, executor 1): java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder; 
local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -2784885576793145316, local class serialVersionUID = -2690984018213736661
```

- I tried a lot of approaches to fix the issue. But couldn't. I think the issue might be the mismatching spark versions of pom.xml spark and spark-submit. Any help here is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance. Also if you have any questions regarding the issue, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens if you have a conflicting version of `spark-catalyst_2.12` JAR that contains the class `org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder`

- So can you please check the classpath of spark-submit in client mode to see from which jar is it taking that class?

Make sure that you are not mixing the classpath to include both the JARs. You can check the "--jars" parameter values.